# How to put page number on very left on even pages and on very right on odd pages using fancyhdr

Tags: fancyhdr

I am using \fancyhead[EL,OR]to put page number on very left on even pages and on very right on odd pages using fancyhdr but it does not work.

```
\documentclass[10pt,openany,oneside]{book}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{paperheight=9.8125in,paperwidth=8in, left=.5in, 
right=.5in,top=.75in,bottom=.4375in }
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{\fancyhf{} \fancyhead[EL,OR]{\textbf 
{\thepage}}\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}}
\pagestyle{plain}
\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{pag}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[hyphens]{url}
\usepackage[authoryear,round]{natbib}
\begin{document}
\newcommand{\titlefontarash}{\usefont{OT1}{pag}{b}{n}\fontsize{25} 
{\baselineskip} \selectfont}
\newcommand{\basefontarash}{\usefont{OT1}{pag}{b}{n}\fontsize{18} 
{\baselineskip} \selectfont}
\title{\titlefontarash  Helping each other}
\author{\basefontarash Good boy}
\maketitle
\frontmatter
\vspace*{\fill}
\begin{center}
\basefontarash To good...
\basefontarash To those good..
\end{center}
\vspace*{\fill}
\tableofcontents
\newgeometry{ left=2.75in, right=.5in }
\mainmatter
\fancypagestyle{plain}{ \fancyhf{}\fancyhead[EL,OR]{\textbf 
{\thepage}\hspace*{2.25in}}\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}}
\pagestyle{plain}
\chapter{Introduction}
\section{Introducing the fish}
\section{fox}
referring to \citet{Fish(1979)}.
A \textbf{fish}  (or \textbf{cat}) jungle sky.
\section{river}
\newgeometry{ left=.5in, right=.5in}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{\fancyhf{}\fancyhead[EL,OR]{\textbf 
{\thepage}}\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}}
\pagestyle{plain}

\begin{thebibliography}{9}
\bibitem[Fish(1979)]{Fish(1979)} Fish, Y(1979) \textit{orange HHH} New York: 
hot.  
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

do u know how to make it work?

Answer (score 3):

When you compile your example, you should notice many warnings like:

```
Package Fancyhdr Warning: \fancyhead's `E' option without twoside option is useless
on input line 29.
```

So you can make your example work like what you want by using `twoside` instead of `oneside` in your options for the `book` class. Actually `10pt` and `twoside` are the default for `book` class, so it is enough to have:

```
\documentclass[openany]{book}
```

Comment: David: thanks for your comment but this adds a blank page with a wrong page number after the title. do you know how to get rid of blank page?

Comment: @ArashRashidi, this is because `\frontmatter` includes `\cleardoublepage`. For a double sided document this is needed, as `\frontmatter` restarts the page numbering also. And without the extra blank page, you get page i on the left hand side instead of right hand side. This is wrong. However, I'll have a guess at what you'd like and include a full example in my answer.

Comment: @ArashRashidi Actually, you can't do it without a blank page. Your front matter has 3 pages (i–iii). The next page is therefore a left side page which is normally even. But then your main matter suggests page numbering again with one, which needs a right hand page. So either you need a blank page after your title, or a blank page after your contents. Or number everything from 1, rather than using roman numbering at the for your front matter.

Comment: Thanks David for your help.